# ZK framework with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, zk

My ZK project doesn't see Jersey MessageBodyWriter when I do request to the server.

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    WebTarget baseTarget = client.target("target");

    Response postResponse = baseTarget.request().post(Entity.text(transaction));
```

add to web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ua.sustavov.payment.service, org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MessageBodyWriter:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class TransactionMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Transaction> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return Transaction.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Transaction transaction, Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        outputStream.write(transaction.toString().getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Transaction transaction, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }
```

When I whant to send request? my App doesn't see MessageBodyWriter
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't see MessageBodyWriter" means. Compile errors, error messages in console, in application server log? Please add the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writer is not going to get picked up by the `Client` automatically, like it would on the server side (when package scanning). You need to explicitly register it

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(TransactionMessageBodyWriter.class);
```

Or you can even register it with the `WebTarget`

```
WebTarget baseTarget = client.target("target");
baseTarget.register(TransactionMessageBodyWriter.class);
```